# PHP: why a line of code appears not to be hit

Tags: php

I'm just starting with PHP and have written a small PHP console program to take 5 test scores and return the appropriate grades plus average.  (I am aware my determineGrade function is incomplete - I left it that way to work on the rest of the program structure first ).

My issue is that this line:

```
echo "Test #{$index}: {determineGrade($grades[$index])}.\n";
```

Inside the second for loop does not produce any output.enter code here

```
   for($index = 1; $index <= 5; $index++)
        {
            echo "Enter Test Score  #{$index}:";
            $grades[$index] = trim(intval(fgets(STDIN)));
        }
    echo "\n\n ==== Results: =====\n";

    for($index =1; $index <= 5; $index++)
    {
        echo "Test #{$index}: {determineGrade($grades[$index])}.\n";
    }

    $average = calcAverage($grades);

    function calcAverage($gradesArray)
    {
        // initialize a variable to hold the sum, calculated in loop
        $sumTotal = 0;
        // start this loop at $index=1 for consistency. Sum the grades.
        for($index=1; $index <= count($gradesArray); $index++)
        {
            $sumTotal = $sumTotal +  $gradesArray[$index];
        }

        return $sumTotal / 5;
    }

    function determineGrade($gradeToDetermine)
    {
        if($gradeToDetermine >= 90)
        {
            return "A";
        } else if($gradeToDetermine >= 80)
     {
                return "B";
           }
    }
    ?>
```

I've tried this with inputs like 87 that ought to produce a result but no go.

Thank you for your help,
Marc

Comment: Is the page erring? Do you get any output from this script, and/or is there anything in the error log?

Comment: What does your http servers error log say, if that script is executed under an http server and not on CLI?

Comment: ==== Results: =====
Test #1: {determineGrade(87)}.
Test #2: {determineGrade(87)}.
Test #3: {determineGrade(87)}.
Test #4: {determineGrade(87)}.
Test #5: {determineGrade(0)}.
Average Grade: 69.6

Comment: It works for me in the terminal.

Comment: ouch... how do I format code inside a comment?  That is my ouput sans linebreaks :)

Comment: Oh, did you mean for your determineGrade function to actually execute in that echo?

Comment: the second loop is producing no output.  Yes, it should execute

Comment: For a function to execute, instead of being parsed as a string, you need to concat the result to the string (assuming a string is being returned from the function): `echo "Test #{$index}: ".determineGrade($grades[$index]).".\n";`

Comment: Aha!  Many thanks!  I was thinking function could work inside the brackets when surrounded by double quotes but I guess thats not the case.  It's working now.  Again, thank you,

Comment: Also, replacing `calcAverage` function with the expression `$average = array_sum($grades)/count($grades)` will give you the same result.

Comment: @MarcHolman SO doesn't allow/want code in comments so formatting is limited here. For code/errors the question should be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [complex string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) (curly brackets in a double quoted string) won't execute your `determineGrade` function. You'll have to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) that into your output instead.

```
echo "Test #{$index}: " . determineGrade($grades[$index]) . "\n";
```

or pass the different pieces as multiple parameters to `echo`.

```
echo "Test #{$index}: " , determineGrade($grades[$index]) , "\n";
```

---

Technically, functions *can* be executed in the curly braces, but only to return the names of variables. See this note from the documentation:

> Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.

So you could use

```
echo "Test #{$index}: {${determineGrade($grades[$index])}} \n";
```

If you happened to have variables named `$A`, `$B`, etc.

This probably won't be helpful to you in this situation, but I just thought I should mention it for future reference since the first part of the answer could be interpreted as not strictly correct.

Comment: Or even a little bit faster: 

`echo "Test #{$index}: ", determineGrade($grades[$index]), "\n";`

Comment: @Reto Is it really faster? The markup is so similar to me I can see that being the only reason to use that method.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I've seen some debate about that. I think the outcome of that is that it is slightly faster, but generally considered a microoptimization. Still, I thought it was worth mentioning as a viable alternative.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Very interesting. I did some benchmarking running 5000 echos 10 times on a page for both types of syntax, and the comma syntax comes out around half the speed of the concatenation. But we are talking like 2-3 millisecond difference so yes I would say very microoptimization